# Creating Indicator from Index Date in R

Tags: r, time, tidyverse, indicator, rowwise

I have a dataframe structured like this

```
df <- tribble(
  ~pat, ~drug, ~`2023-01-01`, ~`2023-01-02`, ~`2023-01-03`, ~`2023-01-04`, ~`2023-01-05`,
  "1", "tylenol",  3, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  "1", "advil",    0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
  "2", "tylenol",  0, 0, 3, 0, 0)
```

I would like to take the values under the respective dates and use them as rowise indicators so my dataframe looks like this. The key is that the non-0 values will be used to populate a rowwise indicator based on its value (i.e. 3 means an indicator for that day, plus two more days).

```
df2 <- tribble(
  ~pat, ~drug, ~`2023-01-01`, ~`2023-01-02`, ~`2023-01-03`, ~`2023-01-04`, ~`2023-01-05`,
  "1", "tylenol",  1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "1", "advil",    0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
  "2", "tylenol",  0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

I would like to output a dataframe with one patient per row that looks like this.

```
df3 <- tribble(
  ~pat, ~`2023-01-01`, ~`2023-01-02`, ~`2023-01-03`, ~`2023-01-04`, ~`2023-01-05`,
  "1", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  "2", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

The goal is to create a df with one row per patient that uses days supply of multiple drugs to create indicators for the proportion of days covered in R (preferably using tidyverse). I have >600k patients, >20 different drugs, and 2.5years worth of data. I have been struggling with this for a while. Can someone please help?? Thank you.

Comment: Why isnt the 2023-01-05 value 1 in the first row, given the original value of 1 on 2023-01-04 there?

Comment: Are your columns always contiguous days or could there potentially be gaps in timing?

Comment: There are a number of approaches to calculate PDC (proportion of days covered) from prescription data. I'm curious to know - what does your raw data look like? Is it a wide data frame with dates as columns, or something else? And in the end, do you just want PDC calculations for each patient?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be pivoting your dataframe and using the values to "spread" 1s down the column until they reach 0. Then summarise to note any days of any drugs.

As untidy as it is to use a `for` loop in R I think it's the only way here, as calculation of each subsequent value in the vector relies on completion of the previous calculation. A function (here `cumlag`) can at least do this in a tidy way:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~pat, ~drug, ~`2023-01-01`, ~`2023-01-02`, ~`2023-01-03`, ~`2023-01-04`, ~`2023-01-05`,
  "1", "tylenol",  3, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  "1", "advil",    0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
  "2", "tylenol",  0, 0, 3, 0, 0)

cumlag <- function(vals) {
  
  out_len <- length(vals)
  
  for (v in 1:out_len) {
    vals[v + 1] <- max(vals[v + 1], vals[v] - 1)
    vals[v] <- min(vals[v], as.logical(vals[v]))
  }
  
  vals[1:out_len]
  
}

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(pat, drug), names_to = "date", values_to = "value") |> 
  group_by(pat, drug) |> 
  mutate(value = cumlag(value)) |> 
  group_by(pat, date) |> 
  summarise(value = max(value)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = value)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'pat'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#> # Groups:   pat [2]
#>   pat   `2023-01-01` `2023-01-02` `2023-01-03` `2023-01-04` `2023-01-05`
#>   <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 1                1            1            1            1            0
#> 2 2                0            0            1            1            1
```